# What is the term for an image sequence with one fixed object in each image?

Tags: terminology, product-photography, marketing, sequences

How is it called if I have movie or image sequence in which one central object is always fixed? For example, the same car in different landscapes, the same kitchen aid in different kitchens, etc.? This is typically used for product marketing movies and I would like to know how this is called. Youtube links, etc., would be appreciated!

Comment: Relevant: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/79739/9161

Answer (score 2):

Instead of timelapse, it is more like **Hyperlapse**.

The difference, IMHO is that Timelapse is using a fixed camera, and hyper-lapse the camera is moving, in this case with the subjet in the same relative position.

Some tips on this other answer: [How to reposition subject in the same place and pose in a series of images over time](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/79739/how-to-reposition-subject-in-the-same-place-and-pose-in-a-series-of-images-over)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there isn't a specific term for this, but I believe it would still be considered a time lapse, just with a static subject as the focal point.